# MonoGame iOS: Where do the assets go?

Tags: ios, monogame

I can get the simplest possible WP7 project converted, but no luck figuring out where the sprite font files, etc should go... I took a look at some Android samples and that didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

You simply add your Content folder to your MonoDevelop project and set the files to the "Content" build type.  All those files will be packaged with the executable.